# Linking c++ projects in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans-8

Bear with me on this one, I am still very new.

So I have ~10 separate C++ projects that build in NetBeans. I want to link all of these projects together, like how you can create a solution in Visual Studios. I then have two other "solutions" that I would like to link to the original first linked "solution" made of ~10 projects.

After this I want to create an executable that will build and compile all of these from one executable.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way I can think of is using makefile, you will need a couple of days to learn about it. Even then, I don't think it will be as convenient as you might want.